# Create new entry in linked database if entry does not exist

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a database with following tables. I use Access from Microsoft 365.

| ID | Title | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | House | Foreign Key Name |
| 2 | Tree | Foreign Key Name |

| Name |
| --- |
| Peter |

The form for the first table has a combo box to select the name from Name-Table.
I want it to create another entry in Name-Table if the inserted name doesn't exist.

`LimitToList = No` didn't create a new entry in Name-Table but saved that text instead of a Foreign Key.

Comment: Use code in NotInList event to enter new lookup record 'on-the-fly' during data entry. This is a very common topic in many forums and blogs. https://blueclawdatabase.com/notinlist-event-code/

Answer (score 0):

to add to J7 post: the combo box control is a combination of a list selector and a text box.... so one can either select from its list and/or enter something manually like a text box...     but that entry does not append to the table which is the record source of the combo box.

the J7 reference provides instructions on how to code that append.

a non code alternative is to label "if not in list" with a button that pops up a continuous form for addition of information to the table... then close the pop up form, refresh the combo box - and that new entry is there...